# execute cut command to every txt files in folder

Tags: bash

I have lots of txt files in a folder which are includes strings in this format:

```
asdasd:asdka
asdkasd:asda
asdk:asdasd
```

I want to take only first part before `:` char, and overwrite it to same text files. I tried this:

```
for i in *.txt; do cat i | cut -f1 -d":" > i.txt; done
```

But I got this error:

```
cat: i: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

Better to use `sed` with inline editing:

```
for i in *.txt; do
   sed -i.bak 's/:.*//' "$i"
done
```

`:.*` will strip out any text starting with `:` and `-i.bak` will save the changes in the original file itself.

Comment: Any reason not to do `sed -i.bak 's/:.*//' *.txt` instead?

Comment: That will also work but if there there are **lots** of matching files as OP wrote then it will give error

Comment: @miken32: Note that your solutions break e.g. if there is file whose name starts with a `-`.

Comment: @phk That would be easily rectified with a `./` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that variables need a dollar sign when you interpolate them. You should also take care to [properly quote](//stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable) any variable interpolation where the variable contains a file name; otherwise, your code will break on file names with spaces etc.

```
for i in *.txt; do
    cut -f1 -d":" "$i"> "$i".txt
done
```

I also took out the [useless `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: You probably don't want files named `*.txt.txt`. If you want to replace the file, the traditional solution is to write to a temporary file and then rename it so it replaces the original; though for this simple and common task, anubhava's answer is probably better. Thanks to @cdarke for bringing this up in his now-deleted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `$` prefix operator from the `i` variable name.  The `$` give the contents of the variable:

```
for i in *.txt; do cat "$i" | cut -f1 -d":" > "$i.txt"; done
```

Note the quotes.

That is a useless use of `cat`, since `cut` is a filter program.  Also, `$i` will *include* the `.txt` suffix.  Worse than that, the `>` will truncate the original file to zero bytes before the file is read!  So:

```
for i in *.txt
do 
    if cut -f1 -d":"  "$i" > "$i.new"
    then
        mv "$i.new" "$i"
    fi
done
```